# popup content menu using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was trying to use whats used in this demo: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/AnimatedContentMenu/

after clicking one of the restaurant menu items the content menu appears.. 
I couldn't use the same code to get the idea of creating a popup content menu.

my question: can anyone help with tutorials or examples of how can I show a popup menu after clicking an  tag?

I hope that my question is clear enough,
thnx

Comment: I really do not understand. You pointed us right to a TUTORIAL asking 'how to do something like that?' What have you tryed so far? Use [this](http://www.google.com) and start [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/)

Comment: Kraz, sorry about that : ) what I want is when the user click a link it opens the content on a new popup box.

Comment: roXon, thnx for guiding me to google! that was brilliant! ;)
anyhow, I did put the link to make my idea clearer. I hope its clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the ppl who have the same question, I finally found something I can use, after applying some changes..
here is the folder: http://www.2shared.com/file/Osok6qFo/popupBox.html

thnx everyone..

Answer (score 0):

The tutorial you're trying to use is too complicated as for the beginning.

Try this one first: http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/2009/02/17/sliding-jquery-menu/

EDIT: now it's clear for me, what you wanted to do, please try this: 
http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Comment: hi jakubmal, I didn't mean a sliding menu, I ment a popup menu.

Comment: does this one look like popup http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-css-example-dropdown-menu/ ? all menus rely on hidden div which is shown when tag is clicked/hovered - it only depends on whether you use slide or fade to show them

Comment: jakubmal, thank u very much for ur response..
the thing I wanna do is opening a popup box after the user click on (Read more...) in articles..
and I'm not that profissional so I don't know how can I adopt this code to make it like wt I want :$

Comment: exactly! 
I'll try it and I'll let u know wt would happen with me.
thank u very much!

Comment: hey! I was working on this example:http://example.nemikor.com/creating-dialogs-on-demand/

this is wt I got: http://www.2shared.com/file/1yW2iE6H/Creating_dialogs_on_demand_fil.html

I have two problems now:
1- it works with all browsers except chrome : S 
2- when I put the code on my asp.net page it says: $dialog.dialog('open'); is not a function. 
is it sort of JS loading problem?

any idea? :$

Comment: it should work when you put it on a server, it doesn't work on chrome locally (that is as physical files on your disk), because in Chrome file:///.../Creating%20dialogs%20on%20demand.html and file:///.../pages/TreadDepth.html are treated as two different domains and AJAX request will not work across different domains